# Fastest way to repeatedly download html contents of a page

Tags: c#, html, multithreading, loops, webclient

What is the fastest way of repeatedly downloading and scanning the html contents of a page like Twitter? I need to check if an username is available many times a second, and the faster the better.

I'm currently making 10 threads that downloads and checks with WebClient and DownloadString, and it's giving me a speed of 5 - 7 checks a second. However I would like it to be faster, is there any way to do this?

Making more threads does not work, just so you don't suggest it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) or for broader web page dumping try [WGET](https://www.gnu.org/s/wget/).

Comment: Doesn't the API have a rate limit? Something about 180 calls per 15 minutes or so?

Comment: Yes, it is described here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting, you may need to look into the **Use application-only auth as a “reserve”** :  "Requests using Application-only authentication are evaluated in a separate context to an application’s per-user rate limits. For many scenarios, you may want to use this additional rate limit pool as a “reserve” for your typical user-based operations."

Comment: In addition to the reserve pool of application-only you can use the credentials of multiple accounts.